# Reading attribute and values into map when key contains another key

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've been using Jackson for a while to parse json files and load the attribute and value into a Map.  This is essentially what my code looks like:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
File file = new File(pathToSource);
map = mapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>>() {});
```

This has worked well for flat json files where the keys are flat, just containing attribute/value pairs.

```
{
   "attr":"value"  
   "attr":"value"
    ...
 }
```

Now one of my sources has begun putting a key inside another key and th readValue method pukes when it hits the inner key.

```
{ "key1":{
   "attr":"value"  
   "attr":"value"
    "key2":{
       "attr":"value"  
       "attr":"value"
     }
   }
 }
```

One caveat of my need is I want to capture the attribute name and the value both. If I parse the json more granularly, taking attributes one by one, I can't access the attribute name.

I've been looking at this for a bit now and can't find the right combination to parse the keys, while capturing the attribute name and value.

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that if you just used simpler version:

`Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(file, Map.class);`

you would get a `Map` that contains `String`s, `List`s and `Map`s as values, corresponding to matching JSON Structure (String, Array, Object).
You can generally use type `java.lang.Object` to mean "use the matching basic Java type", so signature you are asking for is `Map<String,Object>`, unless you want to enforce specific value, or use a POJO type.